# How to include audio in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I am trying to make my program play an audio file when a condition is fulfilled. I am new to Javascript, so I might be making an obvious mistake. I get the error "Cannot call method 'Play' of null." when I run this code.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function EvalSound(soundobj) {
                var sound= document.getElementById(soundobj);
                sound.Play(soundobj);
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: what contains the 'soundobj' Object ... post more ralated code (like where you are invoking this function, html that contains the object ,etc) to get some insight about your problem

Answer (score 0):

You will not go wrong with SoundManager2 - http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/

learn it - love it - live it!

Comment: Okay, I installed soundmanager and it works, but I am getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'play'.

Comment: Actually, now that I look into it, I think this is the error:

Comment: soundManager.createSound(): Unavailable - wait until onready() has fired.